# Pandas remove characters from a column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe with a Date column consisting of stings in this format.  I need to strip the end of the string so that I can convert to a datetime object.

```
"20231101 05:00:00 America/New_York"
"20231101 06:00:00 America/New_York"
```

I have tried these approaches unsuccessfully.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace('^.*\]\s*', '', regex=True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.strip(' America/New_York')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(' America/NewYork'))``
```

as well as a couple of others based on my searches. Is there an easy way to do this or should I write a function to slice the string by grabbing the first 17 characters and assigning the result back to the df.

Note the string could be of the form `'20231101 05:00:00 America/Central'`

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: You might want [str.removesuffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html) rather than str.strip. Notice that you sometimes write `New_York` with an underscore and sometimes `NewYork` without an underscore, is this intentional or is this a typo?

Comment: Thanks that worked and yes it was a typo.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to remove a particular suffix, then I recommend [str.removesuffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html) rather than str.strip.
- Notice that you sometimes write `New_York` with an underscore and sometimes `NewYork` without an underscore. If you ask to remove `'NewYork'` then `'New_York'` won't be removed.
- After the edit in your question, the suffixes all start with `' America'` but differ afterwards; in this case you could use `str.split(' America').str[0]` to keep everything before `' America'`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'Date': ["20231101 05:00:00 America/New_York",
             "20231101 06:00:00 America/New_York",
             "20231101 07:00:00 America/Central"]
})

# df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.removesuffix(' America/New_York')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.split(' America').str[0]

print(df)
#      Name               Date
# 0    Alice  20231101 05:00:00
# 1      Bob  20231101 06:00:00
# 2  Charlie  20231101 07:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the datetime format followed by a space, you could also use [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a capture group and a specific regex, and match the following space.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.extract(r'^(\d{8} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d) ')
print(df)
```

Output

```
      Name               Date
0    Alice  20231101 05:00:00
1      Bob  20231101 06:00:00
2  Charlie  20231101 07:00:00
```